# Proving an equivalence between equalities

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was reading a textbook about topology and I found this proposition :
Let $F$ be a sub-topological space of $E$ and let $A \subset F$.
Then $A$ is closed in $F$ if and only if it exsists $B$ closed in $E$ such that $A=B \cap F $

Here is the proof (the part in bold is the one that I don't understand) :

$A$ is closed in $F$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $F \setminus A$ is open in $F$ $\Leftrightarrow$ **$\exists U$ open in E such that $F\setminus A = U \cap F$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists U$ open in E such that $A = (E\setminus U) \cap F$** $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists B$ closed in E such that $A = B \cap F$

All the equivalences excepted the bold one are straightforward and I can convince myself that this part is right using Venn Diagramm, but I can't find an easy argument that says that this equivalence holds without making a lot of manipulations.

Is there an argument that makes this equivalence true ?

Comment: This is probably given in a stage where the subspace topology is defined: sets are by definition open in $F\subset E$ if they are intersections of open sets with $F$. Based on that it is proved that dually we also have: sets are closed in $F\subset E$ if they can be written as intersections of $F$ with closed sets.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is going on here. I do not have a problem with that, but with an equality only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is we have $F \setminus A = U \cap F$, taking complement with respect to $F$ gives 
$$ A = F \setminus (U \cap F) = (E \cap F) \setminus (U \cap F) = (E \setminus U) \cap F $$
On the other hand, if $A = (E \setminus U) \cap F$, taking $F$-complements gives 
$$ F \setminus A = F \setminus (E \setminus U)\cap F = U \cap F $$

Comment: And why do F-complements not make a $\cap$ become a $\cup$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$Working in a universe $\;E\;$, and writing $\;X^c\;$ for the complement of $\;X\;$ in $\;E\;$, i.e., for $\;E \setminus X\;$, basically your question is: What is a simple proof that
$$
\tag{0}
F \setminus A = U \cap F \;\equiv\; A = U^c \cap F
$$
for any sets $\;F,A,U\;$ with $\;A \subseteq F\;$?

Here is a proof from the definitions, not using any set theory laws; $\;x\;$ ranges over our universe $\;E\;$.

---

Let's start with the most complex side of $\ref 0$, the left hand side, and simplify it:

$$\calc
F \setminus A = U \cap F
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;=,\setminus,\cap\;$}
\tag{*}
\langle \forall x :: x \in F \land x \not\in A \;\equiv\; x \in U \land x \in F \rangle
\op\equiv
  \hints{logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \in F\;$}
  \hint{-- this seems the simplest step forward}
\langle \forall x : x \in F : x \not\in A \;\equiv\; x \in U \rangle
\op\equiv
  \hints{logic: negate both sides of $\;\equiv\;$}
  \hint{-- so that we can exploit $\;A \subseteq F\;$, and to work towards $\;U^c\;$}
\langle \forall x : x \in F : x \in A \;\equiv\; x \not\in U \rangle
\op\equiv
  \hints{logic: reintroduce common conjunct $\;x \in F\;$}
  \hint{-- working towards $\;U^c \cap F\;$}
\tag{**}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \in F \;\equiv\; x \not\in U \land x \in F \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{simplify using $\;A \subseteq F\;$}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\equiv\; x \not\in U \land x \in F \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;{}^c,\cap,=\;$}
A = U^c \cap F
\endcalc$$

---

In essence, the above proof consists of two parts: first we go from $\;F \cap X = F \cap Y\;$ $\ref{*}$ to $\;F \cap X^c = F \cap Y^c\;$ $\ref{**}$, and then we use the fact that $\;A \subseteq F\;$, or in other words $\;A = A \cap F\;$.

The law of logic that was used twice in the first part, is that a common conjunct can be extracted out of both sides of an equivalence:
$$
(R \land P \equiv R \land Q) \;\equiv\; R \then (P \equiv Q)
$$
Perhaps easier to remember is the slightly simpler equivalent that $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$:
$$
(R \lor P \equiv R \lor Q) \;\equiv\; R \lor (P \equiv Q)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an unusual way of thinking but it gets the job done. And most important, I can use it to prove something rigorously (and not use a Venn's diagram to get convinced)